# Get the sensors connected to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors

simple question: is there a way to know which sensors are connected to a Raspberry Pi? I.e., I'm in the Raspberry command line and want to know what's connected to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which sort of sensors ? Ie, internal temperature sensor and etc or external sensor connected via i2c, spi or 1 wire interface ?

Comment: I have this ribbon cable connected to a breadboard on which I deployed a bunch of sensors, I'm talking about those ones :)

Comment: I am afraid there is no such utility in my knowledge. However, you can narrow it down to a specific bus sensors and detect it. For example, if you want to list devices connected to rpi i2c bus, you can make use of i2cdetect utility and like wise for other buses. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh I see, well thanks anyways!